# Twisted alongside Werkzeug

Tags: python, twisted, mod-wsgi, wsgi, werkzeug

Been working on implementing a WSGI app that will answer calls for the data tier in a SOA type project.  After working through some example apps for Twisted and browsing the general community consensus, I discovered Werkzeug and its impressively simple routing library.

I understand that the easily adapted nature of WSGI makes it so that there are many ways to accomplish essentially the same end.  I am just wondering in general if there would be an advantage to using just the routing library from Werkzeug and relying on Twisted for the WSGI server and reactor loop, or if I should ditch Twisted entirely.  Has anyone experimented with the combination?  I should mention that the modules being utilized to perform the business logic in the final app include a ton of blocking calls, so it won't really be practical to make the entire app process asynchronously internally.  More than anything it's just important that the engine can be run as a daemon server itself or plug into apache over mod_wsgi.

Any guidance at all from those with experience with these libraries would be greatly appreciated!  This is new water for me.

**Edit:**

Revising my question for better clarity as per the comments.

I originally came upon twisted more for its roles as a network library than for its expansive asynchronous features.  I had been using it WSGI basic server with the twistd command line tool to test and run a a WSGI application.  There are only a few procedures  within the app that actually need to processes asynchronously, the main thrust of it just has to answer HTTP calls appropriately.

Comment: You didn't really explain what you're using Twisted for now, so it's hard to judge whether you should stop using it or not.